# CSV compressed to the TAR.GZ and upload how to read

Tags: php, csv, upload, compression, tar

Im up to upload the large CSV file so i decided to compress it to tar.gz and upload and uncompress and read the CSV

But i could not get any help from Google i tried to use

```
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt.gz";
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
$contents = gzread($zd, 10000);
gzclose($zd);
```

but it is not giving what i expect to do.

Thank in advance

Comment: What are you expecting, and what are you actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using just parses the `gzip` encoding, not the actual `tar` package.

Take a look at PEARs [File_Archive](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Archive) package, it seems to be able to do what you want.